# Why am I getting an error in the OPTIONS request when making an HTTP POST request in ReactJS and C#?

Tags: c#, reactjs, https

There is an error in the OPTIONS request when making an HTTP POST request.

1. According to the server log, only 4 OPTIONS requests were received, and all 4 were successful.
2. However, in the browser, there were 8 OPTIONS requests, with 4 errors and 4 successes.
3. The host was set and the API was called directly on IIS.

- When calling directly, the OPTIONS request resulted in an error after 1ms.
- When calling through the internet, the error occurred after 200-300ms.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se3m2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3ceF.png)